# SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname not verified

Tags: java, ssl, okhttp, truststore, minio

I am experiencing this exception while trying to use Minio, that uses okHttp3. I have been searching a lot and couldn't find any solution.
These are the steps I did:

1. generated private key
2. generated certificate signing request with subject alt names
3. self signed certificate request with subject alt names
4. added certificate to JRE truststore (jre/lib/security/cacerts)

Absolutely hindering thing. I don't want to modify something in okHttp3 to verify everything blindly. I want a safe solution to this problem. If you can suggest any useful information, thanks in advance.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname 127.0.0.1 not verified:
certificate: sha256/HQpBYmmAI2DSeD1sElkaZB4SpxP1RwUVREMaeWafjq8=
DN: CN=localhost, O=XXX, L=XXX, ST=XXX, C=GE
subjectAltNames: [127.0.0.1, localhost]
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:277)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:238)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:149)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:192)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
at io.minio.MinioClient.execute(MinioClient.java:998)
at io.minio.MinioClient.updateRegionCache(MinioClient.java:1114)
at io.minio.MinioClient.getRegion(MinioClient.java:1160)
at io.minio.MinioClient.executeHead(MinioClient.java:1207)
at io.minio.MinioClient.bucketExists(MinioClient.java:2842)
at ge.minio.Main.main(Main.java:28)
```

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?